# Looking to 'shift' time with PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to be able to shift time if a $_GET['date'] is set.

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date'] !="") {
$date =time ();
}else {
$date =time ();
}
```

I'd like to be able to feed a year & month value through date and still have date equal time but with the time value shifted to the appropriate month and year.

What is the best what to go about this?

Comment: instead of `isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date'] !=""` use `!empty($_GET['date'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend deconstructing the timestamp and then use mktime(...) to reconstruct it with the "fields" of your choosing. You can extract individual "fields" with getdate() or even with date().

```
$f = getdate($timestamp);
$newtimestamp = mktime($f["hours"], $f["minutes"], $f["seconds"], $month, $day, $year);
```

Comment: I see that this is the best way of doing what I want but the code isn't working for me. I have posted the glitched code as another question at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295075/reconstructing-a-timestamp-with-get-values ...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) possibly?

```
$time = time()
--or--
$time = strtotime('+1 year', time());
```

Though I'm not sure I understand the question with how you've worded it.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this? $time = strtotime('year=$_GET['year']', 'month=$_GET['month']', time());

Comment: @PhilipK how about my solution?